# How do I change a date's format in PHP?

Tags: php, date, formatting

I get data from a database in `YYYY-mm-dd` format, but I want to show just `dd.mm` (example - I get `2010-05-28`; I want to show `28.05`)

Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change date format (in DB or output) to dd/mm/yyyy - PHP MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480186/change-date-format-in-db-or-output-to-dd-mm-yyyy-php-mysql) or zillion others

Comment: The duplicate points to mySQL's `DATE_FORMAT()` which is much better suitable for this.

Comment: Someone is desperately need to learn how to use search...

Comment: and why the up vote, anuseful question :D :D :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format the data as it comes out of the database. For example:

```
mysql> select tf, date_format(tf, '%d.%m') from times;
+---------------------+--------------------------+
| tf                  | date_format(tf, '%d.%m') |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
| 2010-11-02 00:00:00 | 02.11                    |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

The fast way is to convert to timestamp and back out to a date. This isn't safe for dates outside the normal epoch though:

```
$dateString = date('d.m', strtotime($dateFromDb));
```

Answer (score 1):

To interchange date formats I use [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) in conjunction with [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), like this:

```
// Assuming the date that you receive from your database as
// YYYY-mm-dd is stored in $row['date']
$newformat = date('d.m', strtotime($row['date']);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To convert the date format from yyyy-mm-dd to dd.mm** in php,

```
<?php

$dt='2010-05-28';
$dt=date('d.m',strtotime($dt));
echo $dt;

?>
```

The o/p will be, `28.05`

Comment: That's what I said almost 2 years before you posted this. You can just upvote my answer or something.