# How i did not added 20 before date in mysql

Tags: php, date

I have issue with this date m/d/y for example 01/09/15 but when i insert that in my table of field name date and declared date i adde to me 2001/09/15 how can i save this format 01/09/15 in field database of my table

Comment: What is the type of the data in your database? It *should* just be a datetime type, at which point it doesn't have a format - you choose to format the values however you want to.

Comment: MySQL usually saves dates in a `Y-m-d` format (or a timestamp).  So, you'd have to insert your date as: `'2015-01-09'`.

Comment: make it DB field as varchar and make your own format.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the format of mysql dates. You could save your date as a varchar but you can't use any manipulation.

You can save it as a mysql date or a time int, and then cast it to the format that you want, using date function.

You can read more about this in this post:
[Change date format (in DB or output) to dd/mm/yyyy - PHP MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480186/change-date-format-in-db-or-output-to-dd-mm-yyyy-php-mysql)

I hope this will be useful.